# Mocha tests are ignored when used within repetitive stream callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

My task is to test some js function against big test vector corpus (10M+), also requirement to test in browser forced me to stream testvectors from local webserver, rather than synchronously read from file record by record.

So, I'm obtaining (one per line ascii) test vectors this way:

```js
const http = require('http');
const readline = require('readline');

FetchTestVectors = function(filename, recordCb) {
  const url = "http://localhost:8080/" + filename;

  http.get(url)
        .on('response', function(response) {
            readline.createInterface({
                input: response
            })
            .on('line', function(line) { 
                recordCb(line);
            })
  });
}
```

And when trying to test it, inner describe-it block becomes ignored (all callbacks).
However, I can see correct console dump.

```js
describe('Test vector set', function () {
        FetchTestVectors('1.input', function (record) {            
            console.log(record);
            //throw new Error("oh no");
            describe('one more vector', function () {
                it('this vector is ok', function(done) {
                    console.log("==" + record);

                    //assert(MyTargetFunc(record));
                    done();                          
                });    
            });

        });
});
```

Also throwing exception (commented line) works strange: it just breaks callback series, with no failing tests in report.

Comment: What is going on in your test suite? You can't nest `describe` or `it` inside another `it`.

Comment: You're right, fixed.  Sorry, I'm just two days mochaing.  However, nothing changed after this  update.

Comment: Specs should be defined synchronously. Placing them inside `FetchTestVectors()` makes them non-existent for test run.

Comment: Does this means, I can't place describe() nor it() inside the callback?  So how I can implement natural test logic - one test per one vector?  The only idea I have for now is to fetch ALL vectors in the array in before() function,  and later test  them synchronously. Not so nice memory hungry solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this means that. Tests shouldn't depend on each other. You can either read them in `before` or re-read them in each test with `beforeEach` or `it`, the latter is generally preferable. Tests doesn't necessarily have to be memory efficient, as long as they don't run out of RAM and serve a good purpose. 10Mb seems reasonable to me.

Comment: *also requirement to test in browser forced me to stream testvectors from local webserver* - this is integration test, not unit test, btw. In unit test, you would take a lot of shortcuts and possibly mock some things. If the intention is to check server response, there should be another test that compares the response with local file. If this was intended as unit test coverage, I'd say testing methodology is wrong.